# Deserializing ServiceBus content in Azure Logic App

Tags: c#, json, servicebus, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to read the content body of a message in an Azure Logic App, but I'm not having much success. I have seen a lot of suggestions which say that the body is base64 encoded, and suggest using the following to decode:

```
@{json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']))}
```

The `base64ToString(...)` part is decoding the content into a string correctly, but the string appears to contain a prefix with some extra serialization information at the start:

```
@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�3{"Foo":"Bar"}
```

There are also some extra characters in that string that are not being displayed in my browser. So the `json(...)` function doesn't accept the input, and gives an error instead.

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in
>   action 'HTTP' inputs at line '1' and column '2451': 'The template
>   language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value
>   `@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�3{"Foo":"bar" }`
>       cannot be parsed: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path '', line 0, position 0.`. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json for usage details.'.

For reference, the messages are added to the topic using the .NET service bus client (the client shouldn't matter, but this looks rather C#-ish):

```
await TopicClient.SendAsync(new BrokeredMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)));
```

How can I read this correctly as a JSON object in my Logic App?

Comment: have you seen this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fbf2391-8440-46db-bb47-648daccf46fd/servicebus-output-json-is-being-wrapped-in-a-xml-header-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps ? Try to send the message as a stream using `TopicClient`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, that thread contains a link to [a separate blog post](http://www.bfcamara.com/post/84113031238/send-a-message-to-an-azure-service-bus-queue-with) which directly answers my question. I've summarized the post as an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* caused by how the message is placed on the ServiceBus, specifically in the C# code. I was using the following code to add a new message:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
var message = new BrokeredMessage(json);
await TopicClient.SendAsync(message);
```

This code looks fine, and works between different C# services no problem. The problem is caused by the way the `BrokeredMessage(Object)` constructor serializes the payload given to it:

> Initializes a new instance of the BrokeredMessage class from a given object by using DataContractSerializer with a binary XmlDictionaryWriter.

That means the content is serialized as binary XML, which explains the prefix and the unrecognizable characters. This is hidden by the C# implementation when deserializing, and it returns the object you were expecting, but it becomes apparent when using a different library (such as the one used by Azure Logic Apps).

There are two alternatives to handle this problem:

- Make sure the receiver can handle messages in binary XML format
- Make sure the sender actually uses the format we want, e.g. JSON.

Paco de la Cruz's answer handles the first case, using `substring`, `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`:

```
@json(substring(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), indexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '{'), add(1, sub(lastindexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '}'), indexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '}')))))
```

As for the second case, fixing the problem at the source simply involves using the `BrokeredMessage(Stream)` constructor instead. That way, we have direct control over the content:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var message = new BrokeredMessage(stream, true);
await TopicClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `substring` function together with `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to get only the JSON substring.

Unfortunately, it's rather complex, but it should look something like this:

```
@json(substring(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), indexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '{'), add(1, sub(lastindexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '}'), indexof(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), '}')))))
```

More info on how to use these functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Paco de la Cruz solution worked for me, though I had to swap out the last '}' in the expression for a '{', otherwise it finds the wrong end of the data segment.

I also split it into two steps to make it a little more manageable.

First I get the decoded string out of the message into a variable (that I've called MC) using:

```
@{base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])}
```

then in another logic app action do the substring extraction:

```
@{substring(variables('MC'),indexof(variables('MC'),'{'),add(1,sub(lastindexof(variables('MC'),'}'),indexof(variables('MC'),'{'))))}
```

Note that the last string literal '{' is reversed from Paco's solution.

This is working for my test cases, but I'm not sure how robust this is.

Also, I've left it as a String, I do the conversion to JSON later in my logic app.

**UPDATE**

We have found that just occasionally (2 in several hundred runs) the text that we want to discard can contain the '{' character. 
I have modified our expression to explicitly locate the start of the data segment, which for me is:

```
'{"IntegrationRequest"'
```

so the substitution becomes:

```
@{substring(variables('MC'),indexof(variables('MC'),'{"IntegrationRequest"'),add(1,sub(lastindexof(variables('MC'),'}'),indexof(variables('MC'),'{"IntegrationRequest"'))))}
```