# Reading message from Service bus

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I have a logic app with started when there is a message in serviceBus queue. The message is being published to the service bus from the DevOps pipeline using "PublishToAzureServiceBus" as a JSON message or from the pipeline webhook.

But getting an issue while converting a message from service bus to original JSON format, not able to get valid JSON object. It's getting append with some Serialization object.

I have tried with base64 decode, and JSON converts but have not been able to get success.

Below is the content of the message it looks like.
[image]

Any pointer on how can solve this?

Sample message sent

```
{
  "id": "76a187f3-c154-4e60-b8bc-c0b754e54191",
  "eventType": "build.complete",
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "message": {
    "text": "Build 20220605.8 succeeded"
  },
  "detailedMessage": {
    "text": "Build 20220605.8 succeeded"
  },
  "resource": {
    "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Build/288",
    "id": 288,
    "buildNumber": "20220605.8",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/*******/_apis/build/Builds/288",
    "startTime": "2022-06-05T14:47:01.1846966Z",
    "finishTime": "2022-06-05T14:47:16.7602096Z",
    "reason": "manual",
    "status": "succeeded",
    "drop": {},
    "log": {},
    "sourceGetVersion": "LG:refs/heads/main:********",
    "lastChangedBy": {
      "displayName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS",
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "uniqueName": "***************"
    },
    "retainIndefinitely": false,
    "definition": {
      "definitionType": "xaml",
      "id": 20,
      "name": "getReleaseFile",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/************/_apis/build/Definitions/20"
    },
    "requests": [
      {
        "id": 288,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/B*****/**********/_apis/build/Requests/288",
        "requestedFor": {
          "displayName": "B*****.sag",
          "id": "*******",
          "uniqueName": "B**********"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resourceVersion": "1.0",
  "resourceContainers": {
    "collection": {
      "id": "*******",
      "baseUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/B*****/"
    },
    "account": {
      "id": "******",
      "baseUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/B*****/"
    },
    "project": {
      "id": "**********",
      "baseUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/B*****/"
    }
  },
  "createdDate": "2022-06-05T14:47:28.6089499Z"
}
```

Message received

```
@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�q{"id":"****","eventType":"build.complete","publisherId":"tfs","message":{"text":"Build 20220605.8 succeeded"},"detailedMessage":{"text":"Build 20220605.8 succeeded"},"resource":{"uri":"vstfs:///Build/Build/288","id":288,"buildNumber":"20220605.8","url":"https://dev.azure.com/*****/********/_apis/build/Builds/288","startTime":"2022-06-05T14:47:01.1846966Z","finishTime":"2022-06-05T14:47:16.7602096Z","reason":"manual","status":"succeeded","drop":{},"log":{},"sourceGetVersion":"LG:refs/heads/main:f0b1a1d2bd047454066cf21dc4d4c710bca4e1d7","lastChangedBy":{"displayName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS","id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","uniqueName":"******"},"retainIndefinitely":false,"definition":{"definitionType":"xaml","id":20,"name":"getReleaseFile","url":"https://dev.azure.com/******/_apis/build/Definitions/20"},"requests":[{"id":288,"url":"https://dev.azure.com/*****/******/_apis/build/Requests/288","requestedFor":{"displayName":"baharul.sag","id":"******","uniqueName":"baharul.*****"}}]},"resourceVersion":"1.0","resourceContainers":{"collection":{"id":"3*****","baseUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/*****/"},"account":{"id":"******","baseUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/*****/"},"project":{"id":"*******","baseUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/*****/"}},"createdDate":"2022-06-05T14:47:28.6089499Z"}
```

When reading message from service bus in peek mode can see as below where <`@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��`> is appended to json string

Publish using PublishToAzureServiceBus from Azure pipeline.
[image]

Publish from Azure DevOps project webhook
[image]

Comment: Can you show the full value by chance?  Also the trigger input json.

Comment: I have added full message in original request now.

Comment: I just tried with the data you provided and I didn't experience any such issue.  Can you provide the payload you get in the trigger?

Comment: @Skin MessageReceived is one that I have received in trigger. You can see <@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�q> get append in message Body.

Comment: No, the entire payload of the trigger, not just the message.

Comment: I can see below format data is coming in body but not sure if can share full contentData as after base64decode its have lots of inormation
"ContentData": "QAZzdHJpbmcIM2h0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbXXXXXXXXX*",
"ContentType": "application/json",
"ContentTransferEncoding": "Base64"

Comment: Got similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223133/deserializing-servicebus-content-in-azure-logic-app but unfortunately it will not solved my case because publisher is out of box provided in Azure DevOps webhook or "PublishToAzureServiceBus" in pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that you have two different types of serialisation in the body of the brokered message created by the PublishToAzureServiceBus task. This is because the brokered message only supports binary content.

So the json is initially serialised as a binary string using the data contract serialiser.

How to solve this? Do the following before passing to your json deserialiser - unfortunately the logic app isn't doing this:

```
byte[] messageContent = brokeredMessage.GetBody<byte[]>(); 
string messageContentStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageContent);
```

I probably wouldn't use a logic app to do the reading of the message because to insert c# like I suggest you're gonna need to call an azure function or similar. I'd create an azure function to read your messages as above.